# How do I send an email and save a copy to my local Microsoft Outlook “Sent Items” folder using POP3 mail server?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail API to send emails from my Microsoft Outlook account. The mail server in use is POP3. How can I program JavaMail to save a copy of the sent email in my local “Sent Items” folder?

Comment: could you elaborate more on *using JavaMail API to send emails from my Microsoft Outlook account* part? i thought JavaMail allows you to send email from Java programs.. if its [Outlook Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/java-tutorial), that would be different case fyi.

Comment: @BagusTesa. Actually, I agree that I was not clear enough. Yes, we are using JavaMail API to give our application an ability to send automated emails. But we wanted to find a way to keep a copy of each email sent by the application in the local outlook Sent Items folder, and this looks like a requirement not possible to be implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unless you can come up with a `Store` implementation for Outlook, but even then it won't work because Outlook will probably be running and have the PST file locked. See [here for Javamail third-party products](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html).

A much better answer to this sort of thing is to use IMAP and save the email in the IMAP Sent folder. Outlook can see those.

Comment: Thanks for this. It has cleared out my doubt and saved my time